# How to run tests of R# plugin from CLI

Tags: unit-testing, resharper, rider, resharper-plugins

I want to execute the tests from [this R#/Rider plugin](https://github.com/matkoch/resharper-fluentassertions) within a GitHub Action and therefore I need to run the tests from the CLI. Simply runnning `dotnet test` does exactly nothing but building the project.

How can I run tests of a R#/Rider plugin from the CLI so that I can embed this step into a GitHub Action?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kind of a bug in our template :) It was missing some references to work with the .NET SDK, more specifically these:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="4.2.1" />
```

Also in this commit: https://github.com/matkoch/resharper-fluentassertions/commit/42fdd20f5c6168402d09b47a7e9e3baa1cc9852c

One remark here: `dotnet test` must be invoked on the solution file (not the test project itself). Otherwise, there was an error about wrong paths. For now, I think that's acceptable.

Comment: Thx man! I had to reference `<PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.13.2" />` as well, but you pointed me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried with `dotnet test`, but they're just nunit tests, so can be run with the nunit command line.